# Can we invoke lambda function with large payload using boto3 library

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I want to know how to invoke a lambda function using boto3 library with large payload. As of now I am able to invoke it with payload less than 6 mb.
Also I want to know what is the maximum limit for the payload.

Once the above issue is fixed...I have another doubt...
How should I pass this payload in the invoke function..
Earlier I was doing it as below :

```
lambda_payload = open('fileName.txt','r').read()
lambda_client.invoke( FunctionName='##FName',  InvocationType='Request Response', Payload=lambda_payload)

# arn copied is in the below format :
# arn:aws:s3:::dev-abc/fileName.txt
```

Now what should be my new payload..

Answer (score 1):

The invocation payload of a lambda can only be 6MB when invoked synchronously or 256KB when invoked asynchronously. An easy workaround for this is to upload your payload to S3 and pass the S3 object location as payload to your lambda. Your lambda can then read or stream the contents of the S3 object.

You could add the S3 URI, S3 object ARN or simply the name of the bucket and the name of the object as string values to the invocation payload. You can then use boto3 inside your lambda function to read out the contents of that file.

If you need a larger payload in order to execute an upload, have a look at [pre-signing S3 URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-presigned-urls.html). This would allow you to return a URL that can be used to upload directly to an S3 location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @stijndepestel.

I have uploaded the file in s3 bucket and have copied the ARN from the folder>properties...
Now how should I pass this payload in the invoke function..

Earlier I was doing it as below :

Comment: @AyushSrivastava I've edited my answer to more clearly explain how to pass the S3 object location to the lambda.

Comment: I passed the above copied arn in the payload in the below format but its not working :
payload = "arn:aws:s3:::dev-abc/fileName.txt"

Comment: I have also tried to paste the S3 URI  and passed it as String in the payload...This too is not working....
Payload = "s3://dev-abc/fileName.txt"

Comment: Please refer to the [boto3 documentation regarding invoking lambdas](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) to see in which format you have to pass in the payload.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Got the output as well. Thanks!

Comment: If your problem is solved, please mark the answer as accepted so the question is solved. thanks